# Cloudfront behind nginx How to setup a Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront and Nginx server (ec2 in US region). I want to access CloudFront via nginx (reverse proxy) and. The issue is that CloudFront is not recognizing the request from the Client instead of Nginx.

For e.g., if the Nginx server is in the US region, and I am accessing it from Singapore, I want my origin should get the viewer country as SG (Singapore), but it gets the country as US.

Nginx config:

```
location /some {

        proxy_pass http://<some>.cloudfront.net/test-request;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```